# My Show or Hide DIV on radio input click has a problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Dont know why, my jquery code is working for hiding a div which is shown initially and show another div with a 'data-value' for first time.
after that it just shows only the displayed div (the another div of the first time) even when other radio buttons are selected.

included jquery : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

my css

```
.stbr{
display: none;
}
```

my html

```
<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='1' value='value'>
<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='2' value='value'>
<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='3' value='value'>

<div class="stbr" style="display: block;">
initial div
<div>
<div id="stb1" class="stbr">
first shown another div
<div>
<div id="stb2" class="stbr">
second div
<div>
<div id="stb3" class="stbr">
third div
<div>`
```

my jquery code

```
<script src="./lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

    var stb = document.querySelector("input");
    var demovalue = stb.getAttribute("data-value");
    $("div.stbr").hide();
    $("#stb"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

i need to get first div on clicking radio input with data-value=1
second div on clicking radio input with data-value=2
and so on....
Please help...anyone

Comment: You hiding only initial element, when should hide all of them on radio change. Add `stbr ` to `stbr1`, `stbr2` and `stbr3`

Comment: is it ok now? i have added divs classes to `stbr`

Comment: It should be Ok. Have you tested it already? Does it works for you?

Comment: it isnt working i tested it already

Comment: Typo here: `$("#stb"+demovalue)` -> `$("#stbr"+demovalue)`

Comment: im only getting the first div...from every radio button

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, you also should update this `var stb = document.querySelector("input");` to this: `var stb = this;` which represents the element you clicked.

Comment: You have wrong ids. Just fix it with what I suggest.

Comment: Or you have different code from what you've posted here.

Comment: yaa u r right... i mistyped it here

Comment: sorry... can you please see it now and get the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have several issues and typos here. You should close your tags with `</div>` and get the demovalue from clicked radio button, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

    var stb = this;
    var demovalue = stb.getAttribute("data-value");
    $("div.stbr").hide();
    $("#stbr" + demovalue).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.stbr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='1' value='value'>
<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='2' value='value'>
<input name='stb' type='radio' data-value='3' value='value'>

<div class="stbr" style="display: block;">
  initial div
</div>
<div id="stbr1" class="stbr">
  first shown another div
</div>
<div id="stbr2" class="stbr">
  second div
</div>
<div id="stbr3" class="stbr">
  third div
</div>
```